Lower bound for sets couples such that $A \subset B$ or $B \subset A$ in some union-closed families
Consider a union-closed family of sets $\mathcal{F}$, with $n = \vert\mathcal{F}\vert$ and thus $n \choose 2$ unordered couples of distinct sets $\{A, B\}$, $A,B \in \mathcal{F}$.
In general, the minimum number of couples such that $A \subset B$ or $B \subset A$ is $n-1$, reached with ${\mathcal{F}} = A \;\cup\; \{B_i \;:\; i=1,\ldots,n-1\},
$ where $A = \{1,2,\ldots,n-1\}$, and $B_i = A\setminus\{i\}$ (see here).
We add the requirement that there must exist $\lceil (n+1)/2 \rceil$ sets in $\mathcal{F}$ such that their union is different from the universe $U(\mathcal{F})$ (the union of all sets in $\mathcal{F}$). This is equivalent to say that not all elements are abundant, i.e. belong to at least half of the sets in $\mathcal{F}$.
In this case, can we get a lower bound $f(n)$ better than $n-1$:
$$\text{Number of couples such that } A \subset B \text{ or } B \subset A \ge f(n) \gt n-1$$?
Any idea?

For $n\ge3$ let $f(n)$ denote the minimum possible number of $2$-element chains in a union-closed family $\mathcal F$ of cardinality $n$ in which not every element of $\bigcup\mathcal F$ is abundant.
The obvious lower bound
$$f(n)\ge n-1+\left\lceil\frac{n+1}2\right\rceil-1=\left\lceil\frac{3(n-1)}2\right\rceil$$
is attained by the family consisting of the $n=h+k+2$ sets
$S\setminus\{x_0,x_1\},\,S\setminus\{x_0,x_2\},\dots,S\setminus\{x_0,x_h\},\,S\setminus\{x_0\},$
$S\setminus\{y_1\},\,S\setminus\{y_2\},\dots,S\setminus\{y_k\},\,S$
where $h=\left\lceil\frac{n-1}2\right\rceil$, $k=\left\lfloor\frac{n-3}2\right\rfloor$, $|S|=h+k+1=n-1$, and   $S=\{x_0,x_1,\dots,x_h,y_1,\dots,y_k\}.$
Hence $f(n)=\left\lceil\frac{3(n-1)}2\right\rceil.$
